# How to properly show Settings window on application start (in WinForms)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, freeze

**Requirements**

A WinForms application that has a settings window (that can be accessed through a menu). On top of that, on application run, before showing the application's window, the settings window should be displayed first. (This forces the user to verify/modify the settings each time the application is run).

**My implementation so far**

Have a `MainForm` and a `SettingsForm`. The `SettingsForm` has a couple of input fields which are saved internally on closing the window. There is a menu entry in `MainForm` to open the `SettingsForm`. In order to display the `SettingsForm` (through the menu entry) I call:

```
SettingsForm settingsForm = new SettingsForm();
settingsForm.Owner = this;
settingsForm.ShowDialog();
```

In order to display the `SettingsForm` before showing the `MainForm`, I call the above code in `MainForm_Load()`, before doing anything else.

**Problem**

On application run, the `SettingsForm` is displayed. But after 2-3 seconds, it freezes.

The `SettingsForm` is "static". Meaning that its only action is to save the input files' values on closing the window.

[EDIT]
The problem was generated by a `Timer` that resided on the `MainForm`. Therefore, the overall design is OK and can be used as a valid solution.

Comment: Not sure if this is what's causing your problem, but in general it's probably not so wise to open a child form of MainForm before MainForm itself has been loaded. Instead, try to use the SettingsForm as the initial argument of `Application.Run()`, and when it's closed, call `Application.Run()` again with MainForm as its argument.

Comment: Based on what you're saying the `SettingsForm` would not freeze. Therefore it is something else which you didn't find interesting enough to tell which is causing the problem. Maybe you're trying to communicate back to the `MainForm` from the `SettingsForm` just as it appears and upon doing so you're entering a deadlock or a message pump lock. Furthermore: It is possible that the "2 seconds" symptom is just the time it takes for the OS to realize that the `SettingsForm` is not willing to respond to messages and in fact it was frozen from second 0

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken I agree. Is is cleaner that way. Still I tried out the conditions explicitly presented in the question and there's no problem with that approach either. I'm guessing Yeseanul is doing something not present in the question which is causing the freeze

Comment: @EduardDumitru I guess you're right: I must be doing something else in the `MainForm` that's causing the freeze. I'm not able to pinpoint it.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken That's a very valid approach ("use the `SettingsForm` as the initial argument of `Application.Run()`, and when it's closed, call `Application.Run()` again with `MainForm` as its argument"). Only thing to use a global variable (`isInitialization`), so that the `SettingsForm` will call `Application.Run(new MainForm))` only once.

Comment: The initial approach was valid. The culprit was a `Timer` that resided on the `MainForm`.

Answer (score 0):

All my project i had setting / user login screen. what i do to prevent this is open the actual main form invisible but within the FormLoad() i call show dialog all the screens i need input. then upon checking all dialogresult if they are valid i let the formload() of the main form continue usually all left is applying filter on dashboard elements that might be on that main form and finally put back visible the form.

i'll alos add you should use opacity and NOT visibility because it cause screen flicker. i noticed on average business computers they are pretty slow and if you set the default visibility in the property grid at design time to visible = false that the form actually show up when the formLoad() is called but then see the property and goes invisible after. on 1.8/2.0 ghz computer with video cards you don't see this much unless you load a crap load of stuff in the load method. I found a workaround is to set opacity to 0. opacity to 0 is set before the form render as i can see from personal result experience (didn't actually check override on paint and stuff like that). so i stopped using visibility if it required to be invisible at start an use opacity instead.